# PDF file scraping to extract html source content

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, optimization, python-multithreading, pdf-conversion

**Goal :** I am trying to convert a **PDF file**(located both locally/on web) to **HTML**.

Using **selenium firefox webdriver** to open the pdf file and extract html content from it using its xpath.

Problem is when the file gets larger the process time increases significantly is there a way to make it faster?

I have tried *threading(python)*, but i have to open a webdriver instance for each page in a pdf file, which takes loading time for each page to open.

*If anything is not clear, iam happy to explain in more detail.*

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: obviously, opening one firefox instance to open one pdf page is supreme overkill. i'm pretty sure any pdf library would be faster

Comment: @diggusbickus ultimate aim is to to extract the html content from browser source element

Comment: ultimate aim means you won't do anything with that data?